# What is the best practice for password posting?

Tags: php, passwords, ldap

I am currently developing a small internal PHP application which requires login. The credentials will be authenticated using LDAP, but I am wondering how secure it is to pass the AD username and password through a form?

Authentication page code:

```
    <?php

// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = $_POST['username'];
$ldappass = $_POST['password'];
// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("SERVERNAME")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: @j08691 Currently no, I have been looking into that however.

Comment: Yeah, consider using a SSL certificate to encrypt the connection.

Comment: @Mahn SSL certificates don't encrypt anything. The encryption algorithm chosen by the SSL *protocol* does that. The certificate is there to provide peer *authentication,* which is a completely separate issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

- https
- Post/Redirect/Get
- Make sure your utility is not connected to the Internet, only your intranet
- CSRF Protection
- Don't store this information in cookies, files, etc.